# Simulates a gravity center in Illustrator or Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, grids

I'm making a retro grid and I would like to make a kind of gravity pit in the center. Problem is that I'm having problems creating effect of grid strokes to simulate that they are affected by the gravity.

I want that this:

[image]

Had in the void part limits with the grid the correct path of strokes, like this:

[image]

To make the effect such the image was like the next gravity effect but seen as aerial perspective;

[image]

Comment: If you dont know how to draw it in 2d draw it in a 3d application instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top down it's merely a series of converging lines and then concentric circles slowly getting closer to each other...

[image]

I used Illustrator's **Polar Grid** tool to create the circle and lines from the diameter.

Then merely select the outer circle and `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform` enter a reduction % for the scale fields and then just add copies.

The tricky part would be getting the bends correctly from the perpendicular grid you have. If you draw it in a 3D app, you could simply rotate the view and export most likely.

Comment: Nice idea! It worked for me. Thanks!